# Infragistics MVC Helper Custom Column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I'm currently using the ASP.NET MVC helpers in MVC4, with the Infragistics igGrid control, and am looking for a way to insert a custom column in order to implement AJAX calls for CRUD functionality. The only solutions that I've found involve exposing the entity which isn't an option in the current architecture.  Essentially I just need to know how to add a new column that can contain a simple href to call an existing REST API that references the model on the specific row.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<div class="queue-grid">
@( Html.Infragistics().Grid(Model).Columns( c =>
 {
     c.For(m => m.DateSubmitted).HeaderText...
     c.For(m => m.RequestorName).HeaderText...
     c.For(m => m.OrganizationName).HeaderText(...
     c.For(m => m.CategoryName).HeaderText(...
     c.For(m => m.DesiredCompletionDate).HeaderText(...
     c.For(m => m.ChargeCode).HeaderText(...
     c.For(m => m.ApprovingManagerName).HeaderText(...
     c.For(m => m.Description).HeaderText(...
     c. //Edit function
     c. //Delete function
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the column template: http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/sample/grid/basic-column-template

```
column.For(x => x.ProductID).HeaderText("Delete").Template("<a href=javascript:DeleteProduct('${ProductID}');>Delete</a>").Width("150");
```

Try that out as your column for delete.

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming release of the jQuery controls (2012.2 - coming really soon), you will be able to define an unbound column with which you will be able solve your case.

What @Boone is suggesting will be absolutely correct - the only difference is that instead of a data-bound column (ProductID in this suggestion), which will expose that column's values in the grid, you will be able to define a blank column.

You will then be able to define a template for that blank (data-unbound) column where you can place links, buttons or anything else you like for that matter.